# Kafka Producer in Java Error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am pretty new to Kafka. I have my Zookeeper server running on port 2181 and Kafka server on port 9092. I have written a Simple Producer in java. 
But whenever run the program, it shows me the following error:

```
    USAGE: java [options] KafkaServer server.properties [--override property=value]*
    Option      Description                           
    ------      -----------                           
    --override  Optional property that should override values set in server.properties file
```

I am using Netbeans IDE with JDK 8 and have included all the Kafka jar files in the Library. I believe there's no error in the library files because the code builds correctly but doesn't run.

Here is the Simple Producer code:

```
package kafka;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Kafka {
    private static Producer<Integer, String> producer;
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();
    public Kafka() {
        properties.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        properties.put("request.required.acks", "1");
        producer = new Producer<>(new ProducerConfig(properties));
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Kafka k = new Kafka();
        String topic = "test";
        String msg = "hello world";
        KeyedMessage<Integer, String> data = new KeyedMessage<>(topic, msg);
        producer.send(data);
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

Kindly help :)

Comment: Where did you get that example code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that Netbeans executes wrong class - not your `kafka.Kafka` class, but `KafkaServer` (it looks like this is a main class of Kafka itself).  Please configure Netbeans to execute correct class.

I would recommend to start with existing sample of Producer from [Confluent Examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/4.0.x/kafka-clients/producer),  and re-use the Maven project...

Comment: Thanks Alex, I imported the classes from `org.apache.kafka` and it worked perfectly! @alex

Answer (score 0):

I think your producer configuration is wrong. Here is an example from Kafka official documentation:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("acks", "all");
 props.put("retries", 0);
 props.put("batch.size", 16384);
 props.put("linger.ms", 1);
 props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
 props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
 props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Just try smaller values for `batch.size` and `buffer.memory`.